# Redis v2.4.10 versus v3.0.7

Tags: redis, version, centos6.5, epel

I'm starting to use redis for my applications as a cache backend and "shared memory" store.

I've asked the servers maintenance team to install Redis on our CentOS 6.5 production environments. From **EPEL**, the version is **2.4.10**, which we hope will upgrade in the future. Also, on our **internal** registry, we have a **3.0.7** available. The maintenance team would prefer the EPEL version.

I'm not quite sure of the differences between the versions. I haven't found a  document listing major changes from 2.x to 3.0. Are there major features/ performance improvements/bugfixes in 3.0 that I *MUST* have?

My first guess is that 2.4.10 would be sufficient enough for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most significant change from 2.x to 3.0 is that Redis 3.0 introduces [Redis Cluster](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec) which is a distributed implementation of Redis.

You can also get change list (bug fix, new features and so on) of other versions from `00-RELEASENOTES` file of each version: [github link](https://github.com/antirez/redis):

Comment: Also I've read that the older versions are usually a subset of newer versions, so I can start with 2.4 and it should be no problem to upgrade afterwards.